# My app works perfect in debug mode but not in ad hoc mode

Tags: ios, objective-c, debugging, adhoc

My app works fine in debug mode, with the simulator or the device pluged to the computer, and when I generate the app for ad hoc and install it in the device, it crashes a lot in random way. Btw, the app is made with Cordova and has background tasks(it's a geolocation app)

Crash example:

```
Exception Type:  00000020
Exception Codes: 0x000000008badf00d
Highlighted Thread:  2

Application Specific Information:
<BKNewProcess: 0x1758f950; com.app; pid: 2675; hostpid: -1> has active assertions beyond permitted time: 
{(
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x17692970> id: 2675-CA057A50-06BF-4BA1-9F0C-7641112B945E name: Called by MyApp, from unknown method process: <BKNewProcess: 0x1758f950; gbi.cro; pid: 2675; hostpid: -1> permittedBackgroundDuration: 180.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:2675 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep  preventSuspendOnSleep ,
    <BKProcessAssertion: 0x17697c30> id: 2675-A03FFC10-1D0A-4BDC-BF64-61358346530E name: Called by MyApp, from unknown method process: <BKNewProcess: 0x1758f950; gbi.cro; pid: 2675; hostpid: -1> permittedBackgroundDuration: 180.000000 reason: finishTask owner pid:2675 preventSuspend  preventIdleSleep  preventSuspendOnSleep 
)}
```

And the thread 2 is:

```
Thread 2 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30ae3518 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x30ae330c mach_msg + 36
2   CoreFoundation                  0x227d1596 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 142
3   CoreFoundation                  0x227cfb5c __CFRunLoopRun + 1012
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2271cb2c CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 472
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2271c93e CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   CFNetwork                       0x222d178a +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 482
7   Foundation                      0x2351e996 __NSThread__main__ + 1114
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x30b75e64 _pthread_body + 136
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x30b75dd6 _pthread_start + 114
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x30b73b80 thread_start + 4
```

I've the whole trace but it's so big, so if someone needs some information, let me know.

Any idea what is it going on?

Thanks

Comment: No one can help you if you don't provide more information. There's a lot of reasons why this might happen.

Comment: Give us the crash logs.

Comment: the problem is that it's so random to get crashes and I can't give more information. I read the debug configuration is different than the ad hoc one, but I don't see where I can change that and set the ad hoc configuration

Comment: You can get the logs off of the device: http://www.chromium.org/developers/how-tos/retrieving-crash-reports-on-ios

Comment: I updated the question with a stacktrace

Comment: Why do you show us NSURLConnection stack trace? Do you use background tasks, if so, do you properly finish them?

Comment: I show you that thread because the log says that it crashed there...And yes, the tasks open and close well. At least when I have the console open...when I archive I just receive the crash

Answer (score 3):

Here's your clue: 0x000000008badf00d.  Go into Xcode 6 documentation, and type 8badf00d.  There's 3 tech notes that cover it. You're getting smashed by the watchdog timer, you have a blocking thread which isn't returning which is taking to long to launch, terminate or allow system services.  Usually it's synchronous network attempt on the main thread.

Comment: It's a good clue...I'm still trying to figure out...I commented the only request I had and it still crashes